# What town is in the Samsung Galaxy S default wallpaper?

Tags: where-on-earth, photography, identify-this, cafes

This is the default wallpaper of Samsung Galaxy S smartphone, does anyone know where this place is?

[image: Samsung Galaxy S default wallpaper]

Comment: A search for "Café des Ducs" (visible at the awning on the left) would point you to Annecy, France, e.g.: http://www.annecy-vitaville.com/ currently features just about the same view on their main page

Comment: this is a great question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is [Annecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annecy) in France.
And you can see on the picture le Palais de l'Isle.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's Annecy and its Old Town. This building is "Le Palais de l'Ile". It used to be a jail and now it's a place for exhibitions.
See more : http://goo.gl/hUoCJm